# Calculate the path of the straight line with logarithmic scale

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

please help with this:

-Calculate the path of the straight line in arithmetic (linear) and **logarithmic.**

The answer would be based on a formula.

x1 = 2 , y1 = 40

x2 = 4 , y2 = 80

x3 = 6 , y3 = ?

I have the solution for the arithmetic (linear) but i would like to know if there are more ways to do it ,  anyway priority is for **logarithmic.**(That is what i do not know how to do it)

[Linear scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvRar.png)

[Logarithmic scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM8vD.png)

To find Y3 in linear scale i use :

y3 = y2 + ( ( (y2-y1) / (x2-x1) ) * (x3-x2) )

Comment: Do you mean an Interpolation?

Comment: im going to add some images , plase wait